# sprintf crashes due to %s in the argument variable

Tags: c++, c, printf, format-specifiers

i have a command of sprintf that crashes due to %s in the aurgument variable. what is the suggested fix for this other than escaping the aurgument string with %%.

```
char* s="abc%sabc";
char a[100];
sprintf(a,"The message is : %s",s);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? The above code should work.

Comment: if you are using c only you can use `strcat` e.g. `a[100]="The message is : ";` `strcat(a,"abc%sabc");`

Comment: I guess it depends on libc implementation. Linux glibc certainly has this bug, and I believe it should be fixed - %s format should not interpolate string being substituted, because it is security risk.

Comment: @mvp That's a pretty amazing bug, how on earth did they get that wrong? BTW %s format should not interpret the string being substituted because it's plain wrong, nothing to do with security.

Comment: @mvp Could you provide some reference to this bug? I don't have any issue with the code above on my Linux distribution.

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? I mean something which demonstrates the problem, but is so complete that we could just paste it in a file and build&run it.

Comment: oops, I take it back. I ran program that sprintf(a, "%s", str) and then printf(a), and of course it interpolated '%s' again.

Comment: @mvp I'm guessing but I think you might have repeated the mistake the OP made.

Comment: guilty as charged! :)

Comment: Vote to close. The code shown does not have the problem claimed, but it is a known problem in similar code (using an already formatted string as a format string). A good question should trim the code to the smallest example still showing the problem, but no further.

Comment: What is the compiler/IDE you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `printf` to print an arbitrary string. Either use `puts` or format the string:

```
char const *evil;

// Bad:
printf(evil);

// Good:
puts(evil);
fputs(evil, stdout);

// Acceptable:
printf("%s", evil);
```

Note that the "bad" version is not just theoretically bad in some stuffy computer-sciency way, but it is actually immediately exploitable to execute arbitrary code and exfiltrate data, thanks to `%n`-like format handling.

Comment: But that's what the OP is doing. The problematic `%s` appears in `evil`, not in the format string!

Comment: @Angew: Yeah. I don't understand the OP's actual problem, so I just gave some general advice which, when followed correctly, should make for string processing free of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Your example works for me: http://ideone.com/ZnsiZZ.

Just use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string):

```
#include <string>  // for std::string

std::string s = "abc%sabc";
std::string a = "The message is : " + s;
```

Or if you need to concatenate other types such as intergers:

```
#include <string>  // for std::string
#include <sstream> // for std::stringstream

std::string s = "abc%sabc";
int i = 42;
std::stringstream sstr( "The message is : " );
sstr << s << "" << i;
std::string a = sstr.str(); // a = "The message is : abc%abc 42"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would stay in C domain only (not use C++).

For me, this code does not crash and prints `abc%abc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char* s="abc\%sabc";
    printf("The message is: %s\n", s);
}
```

but this code prints `abcabc` (without %) and sometimes crashes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char* s="abc\%sabc";
    char a[100];
    sprintf(a, "The message is: %s\n", s);
    printf(a);      // <-- %s is interpolated in printf!
}
```

Most likely your issue here is that you are trying to print string that was created by `sprintf` using `printf` - this does second interpolation and causes all the trouble.

Solution is always use `puts()` to print strings that were created by `sprintf()`.

Comment: i provided sample code in the question. in actual, my function takes ... and i use the following lines va_list arglist;
  va_start(arglist, cFormat);
  vsnprintf(logCharString,sizeof(logCharString)-2, cFormat, arglist);
  logCharString[sizeof(logCharString)-2]=0;
  va_end(arglist);

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string` and your problem will go:

```
#include <sstream> //include this

std::string s = "abc%sabc";
std::string a = "The message is : " + s;
```

If you want to use non-string value such as `int`, then `std::stringstream` would help you:

```
int s = 100; //s is int now!
std::stringstream ss("The message is : ");
ss << s;
std::string a = ss.str(); //a is => The message is : 100
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The stringstream here is useless.

Comment: @Rapptz: Now it is useful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

OP is likely using `printf(a)` to print an arbitrary string `a`.

```
char* s="abc%sabc";
char a[100];
sprintf(a,"The message is : %s",s);
// My guess is that OP follows with
printf(a);  // This causes the error.
```

This fails because `a` is `"The message is : abc%sabc"`.  As a *format* for `printf()`, the function expects another argument becasue of the `%s` in `a` - which is not given and undefined behavior (UB) results.

Instead OP should instead

```
printf("%s", a);
// or
puts(a);
```